# C# Socket Identification Help & Sending Bitmaps

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sockets

So I have a Socket with C# (.NET Framework) and I want to send data to the server from the client however I do not know how to identify what it is to the server. I initially used strings at the beginning of the packet but when sending something like a Bitmap to the server, it didn't work out for me. Someone suggested using integers and what not but I do not know how to do that.

My Client Reading Data

```
        private static void SendScreen()
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        ms.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("screen:"), 0, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("EOF").Length);
        Helpers.GetScreen().Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        var imageData = ms.ToArray();
        var lengthData = BitConverter.GetBytes(imageData.Length);
        ClientSocket.Send(imageData, 0, imageData.Length, SocketFlags.None);
    }
```

My Server Data Reader

```
            byte[] recBuf = new byte[received];
        Array.Copy(buffer, recBuf, received);
        string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recBuf);
        Console.WriteLine("Received Text: " + text);
        string[] brokenText = text.Split(":".ToCharArray());
        Console.WriteLine("EventName: " + brokenText[0]);
```

Comment: Also i don't see how attempting to decode the actual bitmap data as some ASCII string would be meaningful in any way. And considering the probable size of the bitmap (a "screen") the data is probably send as multiple packets, a scenario i suspect you might perhaps also not t handle correctly on the receiving side (although i am just speculating about this last bit, as you didn't reveal the actual code that receives the data).

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace: language, please

Comment: *...I initially used strings at the beginning of the packet...* ok, so you're on the right track thinking-wise. You have to create your own *protocol* (or even better find a suitable one that's already been implemented). One simple protocol is something like: | 8 bytes for the length n of the data | n bytes of the data |. This allows your receiving program to know at the beginning how many bytes it needs to read. Now if you have different types of data you can modify the protocol to | 8 bytes for length n | 1 byte for type | n bytes of the data |. Note that many people  might just use JSON.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Do you have any examples or any code for JSON and/or for the custom protocol you were describing?